# How to get information from Google sheet using API

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to send data from google sheet using POST.

Actually it works, if I write data in code. But I wand to get it from google sheet

My code is below :

```
function sendDataToRoistatAPI() {
  var url = "https:XXX";
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Users"); 

  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var rowData = data[i];
    var payload = {
      manual_custom_metric_id: rowData[1], 
      source: rowData[2], 
      value: rowData[3], 
      period: rowData[4], 
    };

    var options = {
      method: "post",
      contentType: "application/json",
      payload: JSON.stringify(payload),
    };

    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
    Logger.log(response.getContentText()); 
  }
}
```

The mistake is :

```
{"status":"error","error":"incorrect_request","description":"Argument value is not a positive value\nRequired argument period is missing\nArgument manual_custom_metric_id is not a positive integer number"}
```

In google sheet named Users I have colums: `manual_custom_metric_id,source,value,period`
[That's how my google sheet looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Nl6h.png)

Comment: Disn't you mean this to be `payload: JSON.stringify(payload)`?

Comment: Oh, yes, but mistake is still the same

Comment: You probably have some negative numbers in the first column that are not supported by the API you are trying to call. The error seems to be from the API, it has nothing to do with App Script. It's generally considered a bad practice to send user input without validating it. Spreadsheet cells support user input so their contents must be validated. For example, cells may contain trailing spaces, strings mixed in with numbers, line breaks, etc. All of this can break your code. You need to validate your request parameters before sending.

Comment: Although I cannot know the specification of the API you want to use and your Spreadsheet, for example, from `In google sheet named Users I have colums: manual_custom_metric_id,source,value,period` and your showing script, if your Spreadsheet has the 1st header row, I'm worried that your script uses the header row. If my guess was correct, how about skipping the 1st header row by modifying `var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();` to `var [,...data] = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();`? But, if my guess was not correct, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike I attached a screenshot of how my google sheet looks like. Still it doesn't help

Comment: @AntonDementiev I attached a screenshot of how my google sheet looks like. It doesn't have negative numbers

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your provided sample Spreadsheet image, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Please confirm it. In that case, from `Actually it works, if I write data in code.`, I suppose that your URL and the actual values in the cells are valid values for using your API. Please be careful about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- From your showing sample Spreadsheet image, I think that in your showing script, `data` of `var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();` includes the 1st header row. And, in your for loop, the 1st header row is used. In that case, the header titles are used in the values. I thought that this might be an issue.
- In your Spreadsheet, columns "A" to "D" are used. And, in your showing script, the values of `rowData[1]` to `rowData[4]` are used. In this case, the script uses columns "B" to "E". In this case, I guessed that `period: rowData[4],` might be column "D". The 1st index of the array is 0. I thought that this might be an issue.
- In your Spreadsheet, the values of column "D" are the string type. So, `rowData[4]` of `period: rowData[4],` is a string value. I thought that this might be an issue.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function sendDataToRoistatAPI() {
  var url = "https:XXX";
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Users");
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  // I modified the below script.
  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    var rowData = data[i];
    var payload = {
      manual_custom_metric_id: rowData[0],
      source: rowData[1],
      value: rowData[2],
      period: JSON.parse(rowData[3]),
    };
    var options = {
      method: "post",
      contentType: "application/json",
      payload: JSON.stringify(payload),
    };

    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
    Logger.log(response.getContentText());
  }
}
```

#### Note:

- Unfortunately, I do not know the actual Spreadsheet. So, I have no information on whether the values of column "C" are the number values. If the values of column "C" are the string type, please modify it to the number type and test it again.
- In your showing script, the access token or the API key is not used. Is this the correct situation? If the access token or the API key is required to be used, please provide the information about the specification of the API.

Comment: I have api in url, so that's fine. This is how I send data in code:  var data = {
  manual_custom_metric_id: 4,
  source: "Visits",
  value: 9999,
  period: {
    "from": "2023-03-31T21:00:00",
    "to": "2023-04-13T20:59:59"
            }
  }; and it worked

Comment: Your issue doesn't work, unfortunately. The mistake is still the same

Comment: @Michael T Can you provide the script of `var data = { manual_custom_metric_id: 4, source: "Visits", value: 9999, period: { "from": "2023-03-31T21:00:00", "to": "2023-04-13T20:59:59" } }; and it worked`?

Comment: @Michael T And, it seems that the values of `var data = { manual_custom_metric_id: 4, source: "Visits", value: 9999, period: { "from": "2023-03-31T21:00:00", "to": "2023-04-13T20:59:59" } };` are different from the values of your showing spreadsheet. How about this? And, can you provide the Spreadsheet including your current script for correctly replicating your current issue? By this, I would like to confirm it. I thought that in this case, it is required to correctly understand your situation. I apologize for this.

Comment: `function sendDataUsingPOST() {
  var url = "https:// XXX";
  
  var data = {
  manual_custom_metric_id: 4,
  source: "Visits",
  value: 9999,
  period: {
    "from": "2023-03-31T21:00:00",
    "to": "2023-04-13T20:59:59"
            }
  };
 
  var headers = {
    method: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    payload: JSON.stringify(data),
 //   Api-key: "{27b9c190a9442a8faf3a38fa70f27d18}"
  };
  

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, headers);
  var content = response.getContentText();
  
  Logger.log(content);
}`

Comment: the fomat of data in my google sheet is exactly the same. I'm not sure that the problem is in this

Comment: @Michael T Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my very poor skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your current situation. In this case, it is required to correctly confirm your situation. So, can you provide your sample Spreadsheet including your current script of my proposed script for correctly replicating your current issue? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: @Michael T By the way, from your script in your comment, I understood that `var data = { manual_custom_metric_id: 4, source: "Visits", value: 9999, period: { "from": "2023-03-31T21:00:00", "to": "2023-04-13T20:59:59" } };` is used as `payload: JSON.stringify(data)`. In this case, it seems that the values in your spreadsheet image are different from your tested values. How about this?

Comment: @Michael When I put the values of `4`, `visits`, `999`, `{"from": "2023-03-14T21:00:00", "to": "2023-04-15T20:59:59"}` into the cells "A2:D2" and I run my modified script, `JSON.stringify(payload)` is `{"manual_custom_metric_id":4,"source":"visits","value":999,"period":{"from":"2023-03-14T21:00:00","to":"2023-04-15T20:59:59"}}`. And, in your script in your comment, it seems that you use API key. But, that is not the correct part. If you want to use the API key in the request header, please add `headers: {"Api-key": "###your API key###"}` in `options`.

Comment: I don't know how I didn't change anything, but it works. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: @Michael T Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.